# Angular weird popup

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

[image]

Does anyone know why when I enter anything on the input box, the success notification will appear on the top of my screen? BTW I am using MDBootstrap to design all this.

**This is one of my input box example code**

```
  <input mdbInputDirective type="text" class="form-control" style="border:1px solid" formControlName="s_address">
  </div>
```

**This is the solution**

```
  <input mdbInputDirective [mdbValidate]="false" type="text" class="form-control" style="border:1px solid" formControlName="s_address">
  </div>
```

Comment: By notification do you mean the big red box?

Comment: Can you add the html for that success notification. I suspect that you're starting to update the state of the form and the success notification is checking for the wrong variables to become visible.

Comment: no, i mean the word "success" appeared on the big red box. As you can see there are many "success" there.

Comment: Gotcha can you add the html for that success code.

Comment: @BaileyMiller i did not add any success notification or code haha. Its just appeared there if i put something on the input box

Comment: So if you go to this page without typing anything there isn't success text. You then start typing and it shows up?

Comment: @BaileyMiller yap, its nothing if i dont start typing

Comment: Try using chrome debugging tools to look at that success notification

Comment: Ok, proble solve